# Too may redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a similar problem to someone else where I keep getting too many redirects

So added the code suggested below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sheffieldresidential.com/sheffield-property-blog 
{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

but still getting the re-direct error

```
<!-- 
# Only allow direct access to specific Web-available files.

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Akismet CSS and JS
<FilesMatch "^(form\.js|akismet\.js|akismet\.css)$">
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Allow from all
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all granted
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Akismet images
<FilesMatch "^logo-full-2x\.png$">
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Allow from all
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all granted
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
nd -->

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sheffieldresidential.com/sheffield-property-blog 
{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Does the error go if you clear your browser cache?

Comment: When it is sent to https://...., does that apache also have redirects?  It might loop between this and the other site.  Other detail, this could be a cut-paste problem, but your line `{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]` should not be alone like this but combined to the previous line.  Please correct.

Comment: Hi, do you mean to move the the line {REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE to be moved up?